# need to remove special characters in the midle of sentence but not starting and ending of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
string= "& & This is&test release & this is rest release &";
Output ="& & This istest release  this is rest release &"
```

Input:

```
string ="& & This is&test release & this is rest release &";
```

Output should be

```
"& & This istest release  this is rest release &";
```

But am getting output is

```
"& & This istest release & this is rest release &";
```

My code:

```js
var str = "& & & This is&test release * this is rest release & &";
var str2="";
var str1=str.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
 if(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(str1[i])) { 
   str1[i]=str1[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "") 
 }
 str2=str1.join(' ');
}
console.log(str2);
```

Comment: What is your code? What are the actual requirements?

Comment: Hi tried like this

Comment: <script>
var str = "& & & This is&test release * this is rest release & &";
var str2="";
var str1=str.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<str1.length;i++){
if(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(str1[i]))
 {
 str1[i]=str1[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
  }
str2=str1.join(' ');
 }
alert(str2);
</script>

Comment: Try  `str.replace(/(^[^\w\s]+|[^\w\s]+$)|[^\w\s]/g, "$1")`

Comment: Just added your code to the question and you actually get `& & & This istest release * this is rest release & &`. It looks expected.

Comment: @user2644839 You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the white spaces in string here (do you actually need them ,but here's an alternative you can try)

```js
let string = "& & This is&test release & this is rest release &";

let a = string.split("&").map(el => {
  if (el == "" || el == " ") {
    el = " &"
    }
  return el
})
let result = a.join(""); // join acc to gap you want
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let s= "& & This is&test release & this is rest release &";

let o= s.replace(/^([& ]*)(.*?)([& ]*)$/, (m,a,b,c)=> a+b.replace(/&/g,'')+c);

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with that will work with any special characters.

```
var str = "& & This is&test _&&release & this_is rest release &";
var replacedString = str.replace(/(\w\s*)([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s*\w)/g, "$1 $3"); 
console.log(replacedString);
```

**Output:**

```
& & This is test  release  this is rest release &
```

The replace pattern will match any number of special characters between any alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

what about this? it works perfectly.
I splitted the string to start, middle and end. then replaced the special characters only in the middle, and then joined all the 3 parts back.

```js
string= "& & This is&test release & this is rest release &";

i=string.search(/[\w\s]/i)//first letter
j=string.search(/[\w\s][^\w\s]*$/i)//last letter

start=string.substr(0,i)
middle= string.substr(i,j-i+1)
end=string.substr(j+1)

middle=middle.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi,"")//replace only in the middle

output=start+middle+end

console.log(output)
```

Hoped I helped you.